# Dates of previous highest values

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have a table with two columns ( date of measurement and maxtemp). I would like to write a query that gives me the following result:

1. Date of highest value as date1, value
2. Date of highest value where date < date1 as date2, value
3. Date of highest value where date < date2 as date3, value
4. Date of highest value where date < date3 as date4, value
   ...

Table displaying the dates of beating the next temperature records.
I'm a hobbyist and I'm still weak and I have no idea how to solve it. Thanks for answers :) 
In the red frame is what I have in the table, column "actual hihest value" is an assistant 
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qrB5.jpg)
Here is my wanted result:
[wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwiwN.jpg)

Comment: Please provide an example. Your problem statement isn't clear.

Comment: I added screenshots with example :)